# Getting ResourceNotFoundException even though table exist in Dynomodb using python

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb

I was able to hit the region and able to fetch available tables but when i do get_item method on existing table it returning back with ResourceNotFoundException(Resource not found), please take a look at below code and help me out. Thanks

```
import argparse
import boto3
import boto
import boto.dynamodb

def remove():
    conn = boto.dynamodb.connect_to_region(
        'us-west-2',
        aws_access_key_id='<key_id>',
        aws_secret_access_key='<secret-key>')

    res = conn.list_tables();
    print(res) #listed all tables 
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    table = dynamodb.Table('<table-name>')
    des = conn.describe_table('<table-name>')
    print(des) . # describing the table 
    response = table.get_item(
            Key={
            'id': '<id>'
         }
    )   
    item = response['Item']
    print(item)
```

Comment: Looks like your structure definition does not fit the state of the database.

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, there are not enough information to get more detailed.

Comment: the main objective of the code in to get the specific item from dynomodb table. i was able to connect region `us-west-2` and able to list the tables. i took table from above listed items and able describe it. But when i do get_item on the same table i am getting the resource not found.

Comment: @Lohith : How did you resolved your issue ? I think I am getting a same kind of error...